# AVPlayer with downloaded content doesn't work but streaming content does

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, nsfilemanager

I am trying to (1) download a piece of audio from a link, (2) add that newly-downloaded audio to an AVPlayer and (3) play it.  Something is going wrong at step (3) and I'm looking for any guidance. Here's the code, including my alamofire and download functions, as I fear something may be going wrong at that stage.

```
import AVFoundation

class SettingAlarmViewController: UIViewController {

var player:AVPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch {
        // report for an error
    }
}

func getLatestPodcastURL(completion: @escaping (URL) -> ()) {

    let RSSUrl: String = "https://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510318"

    Alamofire.request(RSSUrl).responseRSS() {response in
        if let podcastURL: String = response.result.value?.items[0].enclosure! 
       {
            let audioURL = URL(string: podcastURL)
            completion(audioURL!)
        }
        else {
            //error handling
        }
    }
}

func downloadSongAsynch(audioUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (URL) -> ()) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsDirectoryURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("podcasts/")

    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.path,
                                        withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
    //error handling
    }

    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)

    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
        guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
        } catch {
            //error handling
        }
    }).resume()
    completion(destinationUrl)
}

@IBAction func SetUpBotton(_ sender: Any) {
    getLatestPodcastURL() {response in
            //Uses an asynchronous call to Alamofire to get the podcast URL
            self.downloadPodcastAsynch(audioUrl: response){response2 in
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: response2)
                print(self.player.currentItem)
            }

@IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: Any) {
    player.play()
    print(player.currentItem)
}
```

The log consistently shows my current item: >

But nothing plays. I have checked that the audio is working by trying to use the URL to stream this content. That works fine. I am getting the following:

> BoringSSL errors "[BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

but from what I've read, this is just a bug in the latest update and shouldn't be impacting the download.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Here I am four years later with the same issue, I can stream but I cannot play what I locally downloaded unfortunately